# Why is my single line input only partially read by the loop?

Tags: c++

First I get the input for the switch in a character 'geotype'

```
char geotype;
cin>>geotype;
```

Then I get the number of points followed by the individual coordinates with a for loop.

This is the problematic part if my code :

```
int i;
double xp[n], yp[n];

switch(geotype):
{     
     .
     .
     .

     case 'P':

        cin>>n;

        for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            cin >> xp[i] >> yp[i];
            cout << "i = " << i <<" ";
            cout <<"xp = " << xp[i] <<" yp = "<< yp[i]<<endl;
        }

        .
        .
        .

        break;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

My input is :

```
P 2 3 -2 -1 4
```

My output is :

```
i = 0 xp = -2 yp = -2
i = 1 xp = 4 yp = 4
```

Why are 3 & -1 skipped?

Also, how are -2 & 4 duplicated since they are occurring only once in the input.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is the error:

```
double xp[n], yp[n];
```

So your `n` is possibly 0 at this moment, and you create arrays of zero size. Since they have size zero, the location of `yp = xp + 0 = xp`. So `yp` and `xp` point to the same location. Since there is no bound checking, you are writing outside of bounds, and `xp[i]` has the same location as `yp[i]`.

The solution is

```
int* xp, *yp;
// When handling P
xp = new int[n];
yp = new int[n];
```

Or better use vectors.

Comment: I moved the double xp[n], yp[n] to after the cin>>n. This worked. Thank you !

Comment: @Krishna21 What you're using isn't valid C++, because standard C++ doesn't have variable length arrays. Your code only compiles because of a non-standard compiler extension that comes with all sorts of problems. Also don't use `new`, because that is completely unnecessary and causes confusion and memory leaks. Instead, learn to use `std::vector`.